# rest service: cannot get whole data from @Comsumes() ( by javax.​ws.​rs.Comsumes )

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a rest service by Java and the request that invokes the REST service contains a JSON object.

I found sub_array_1 and sub_array_2 were empty Lists but other class members have their values in receviedObj.

Does @Consumes() cannot parse more than 1 level json object ?
How could I get correct data in sub_array_1 and sub_array_2 ?

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
/* ... */

@POST
@Path("")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sendRequest(ClassB receviedObj) {
    /*  ...  */
}
```

json object likes:

```
{
  "item_1": "value_1",
  "item_2": "value_2",
  "item_3": "value_3",
  "otherItems": [
      {
          "subitem_1": "subvalue_1",
          "subObject": {
            "name": "aaabbb",
            "sub_array_1": [
                {
                    "data_1": "d11",
                    "data_2": "d12",
                    "data_3": "d13"
                },
                {
                    "data_1": "d21",
                    "data_2": "d22",
                    "data_3": "d23"
                }
            ],
            "sub_array_2": [
                {
                    "tag_1": "v1",
                    "tag_2": "v2",
                    "tag_3": "v3",
                    "tag_4": "v4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

java class:

```
public class ClassB {
    public String item_1;
    public String item_2;
    public String item_3;
    public List<otherItems> otherItems;
}    

public class otherItems{
    public String subitem_1;
    public subObject subObject;

    public otherItems(){
        this.subitem_1 = "";
        this.subObject = new subObject();
    }

    // ================================
    public static class subObject{
        public String name;
        public List<sub_array_1>  sub_array_1;
        public List<sub_array_2>  sub_array_2;

        public subObject(){
            this.name= "";
            this.sub_array_1 = new ArrayList<sub_array_1>();
            this.sub_array_2 = new ArrayList<sub_array_2>();
        }
    }

    // =========================================
        public static class sub_array_1 {
            public String data_1;            
            public String data_2;
            public String data_3;

            public String getdata_1() {
                return data_1;
            }

            public String getdata_2() {
                return data_2;
            }

            public String getdata_3() {
                return data_3;
            }
        }
        public static class sub_array_2 {
            public String tag_1;
            public String tag_2;
            public String tag_3;
            public String tag_4;

            public String gettag_1() {
                return tag_1;
            }

            public String gettag_2() {
                return tag_1;
            }

            public String gettag_3() {
                return tag_1;
            }

            public String gettag_4() {
                return tag_1;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I still cannot figure out why JSX-RS cannot convert JSON to java class correctly.

I use Gson to do the conversion and get the object with correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the JSON you are sending is appropriate for `ClassA` as it has some params which are not there in `ClassA`. Params like item_1, item_2 etc. Per my test, following JSON should populate `ClassA` fine.

```
{
  "subitem_1": "subvalue_1",
  "subObject": {
    "name": "aaabbb",
    "sub_array_1": [
      {
        "data_1": "d11",
        "data_2": "d12",
        "data_3": "d13"
      },
      {
        "data_1": "d21",
        "data_2": "d22",
        "data_3": "d23"
      }
    ],
    "sub_array_2": [
      {
        "tag_1": "v1",
        "tag_2": "v1",
        "tag_3": "v1",
        "tag_4": "v1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, either you need to change `ClassA` to incorporate other fields or you need to use above JSON. Also, I suggest some reading on coding practices and naming conventions for Java

Comment: Oops, I forgot to write down another class ... let me edit that. Sorry for the mistake and thank you for your advice.

Comment: I updated this article about java class part, and I still cannot get sub_array_1 and sub_array_2 (but all other class members were okay.)